# K2 Joomla Extra Fields: How do I refer to extra fields by name/id instead of key?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-k2

I am trying to use extra fields in K2. I do it all the time - but in this case, sometimes some fields have values, and others don't. So the key is not consistent.

Is there a way for me to refer to them by name or id instead of by key of the automatic array?

I tried this and it does not seem to work:

```
$streetaddress = $this->item->extra_fields->id[249];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this great script [here](http://getk2.org/community/New-to-K2-Ask-here-first/161676-Display-specific-extra-field-in-module-position-) for converting extra fields to use either id or label as key:

```
<?php 
 //convertArray to use ids as key
      $extrafieldsid = array();
      foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $itemid)
      {    
      $extrafieldsid[$itemid->id] = $itemid->value;
      }   
      ?>
       <?php 
 //convertArray to use labels as key
      $extrafieldslabels = array();
      foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $itemlabel)
      {    
      $extrafieldslabels[$itemlabel->id] = $itemlabel->name;
      }   
      ?>
```